# AWS Servers time issue

Tags: service, amazon-web-services, timezone

I have two servers running in the same private cloud within AWS.

For some reason Server 1 is always roughly 2 minutes behind Server 2. I checked the "Windows Time" service on both servers and I found that that service was disabled for Server 1. So I enabled it and thought that that should resolve my issue. I can still see observe this issue though. Can you please help me? I have set both Servers to automatically obtain time from "time.windows.com"

This is crucial to me as Server 2 calls Server 1 and asks for updates using it's local timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I resolved this issue was to install [Tardis 2000](http://www.kaska.demon.co.uk/).

> Tardis is a shareware utility for Windows that makes sure your PC’s clock tells the right time. It can find out what the right time is in various ways including accessing Internet-based Atomic Clocks, using networked timeservers, GPS (The Global Positioning System), Radio clocks, and by listening for time broadcasts over a LAN.

Now both servers are in sync and there are no time issues anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Time sync is always an issue with virtual machines. You will probably need to sync more than once per week. Set up a scheduled task with the `W32tm.exe` tool to run it every hour or so.

Comment: The servers go out of sync every hour. I do understand that there can be a few seconds difference between them but every hour? That just does not make any sense. How can I do this using W32tm.exe?

Comment: Time sync is a common problem in virtualized environments. Resources are shared, and not all ticks may get sent to the guest machine. You will need to set up a scheduled task with the command `W32tm.exe /resync`. It will probably need administrator permissions.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work as the server time drifts around 833 seconds per day! Please see my answer below on how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this thread could also be helpful for those who are not interested in purchasing a 3rd party solution that may or may not be reliable.

It suggests changing the polling from 60480 seconds to 60 secons and not using windows time server.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=428855